# Uploaded files aren't displayed

Tags: 7, ubercart, files

I'm using ubercart for a poster printing process. It allows users to upload files for poster printing. 
But in the order page where I can see the summary of the order, the section for `Upload File` displays as `Upload File: Array` instead of a link to the uploaded file.

Has anyone run into this problem before, or someone can point me to the module file that generates this section?

NOTE: The files are uploaded correctly, I can see them stored in the file directory.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry? Can you expand on what you mean by `displays as Upload File: array`? And how are you getting the file? There is a trick to Drupal to get the file stuff.